# Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration

Tags: android

When I run Studio, Grade Build shows the error message like this

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':tiangua'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':tiangua:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find any version that matches com.github.mmin18.layoutcast:library:1.+.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            file:/E:/android/adt/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/github/mmin18/layoutcast/library/maven-metadata.xml
>            file:/E:/android/adt/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/github/mmin18/layoutcast/library/
>        Required by:
>            code:tiangua:unspecified